# How to go up one directory using Markdown

Tags: syntax, directory, markdown

Within the markdown document, what is the proper syntax to go up one directory and then choose the file? It will be rendered online, so would html ../ be appropriate to put in the markdown syntax?
such as [some_description]andthen(../file_name.md)
I had to add the "and then" to get it to show up on stack....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Links work the same way in Markdown as they do in HTML. A relative path would work the same way.

`[I'm a relative reference to a repository file](../blob/master/LICENSE)`

which is from here: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#links